# What is a possible way to create an in app PDF viewer with React Native and Expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm working on an app for a financial company. They want the statements which are in PDF be accessible within the app for viewing. I'm having a hard time finding a solution since any libraries with a PDF reader would require ejecting from expo which I need to avoid.

I've been trying to use the expo-web-browser hoping I can keep it contained within the app kind of like how it works with authentication.

Any insights?

Comment: "I've been trying to use the expo-web-browser hoping I can keep it contained within the app" - so is this approach working for you or not? What issues are you experiencing?

Comment: You can, but using a lib like https://github.com/rumax/react-native-PDFView#readme

Comment: Did you find a solution or a way to build a PDF viewer on Expo?